# Cockpit - Where is the bridge configuration kept?

Tags: server, cockpit

I recently created a bridge for my VMs inside cockpit
( Ubuntu LTS Server -20.x)  and used it in my VMs.
They work fine.

My understanding of cockpit was that it will use system configuration files for its tasks
but however opening up my netplan configuration at
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
I can see no definition for the bridge ( br0 ).

So any idea where the bridge configuration is kept when its created via cockpit ?

Thanks.

UPDATE 2 :

Solved. See answer

UPDATE 1:

As advised by @user535733
I have also looked at locations:

/usr/lib/systemd/network/
/usr/local/lib/systemd/network/
/run/systemd/network/
/etc/systemd/network/

but no br0 related settings there.

Comment: @user535733    - Checking now ... did not know of these locations ...

Comment: @user535733 - Nothing related there. Updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: @user535733 - the renderer in /etc/netplan/   is -> renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: @user535733 - the renderer line was non-existent in the initial setup, but i had to add renderer: NetworkManager  to overcome failure to update software via Cockpit ( It gave error   "Cannot refresh cache whilst offline ".

Comment: @user535733 - the location you gave was correct. Kindly add it as an answer and i will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your netplan configuration.

If your renderer is networkd (common for servers), then check the following locations for the config files:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/network/
/usr/local/lib/systemd/network/
/run/systemd/network/
/etc/systemd/network/
```

If your renderer is NetworkManager (common for desktops), then check the following location for config files:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

- You can also interact with NetworkManager using `nmcli` instead of browsing or editing NM config files manually.

Comment: Thanks ..... Much appreciated.

Comment: One more thing ...  shouldnt  /etc/netplan/the_yaml_file  hold the bridge configuration if the renderer is networkd ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.